# Excel: Count how often employees work together in a week?

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

in Excel i tried to count employees working together on a project (e.g. Project-A) in a whole week. 
10 different people work together based on the scedule below.
Every day two are are working on the same project, the next day on another.

```
Employee | Monday    | Tuesday   | Wednesday | Thursday  | Friday    | Saturday  | Sund.
Bob      | Project-A | Project-C | Project-B | Project-C |           |           |
Jennifer | Project-B | Project-D | Project-A | Project-D |           | Project-C |
Tom      |           | Project-B | Project-C | Project-A | Project-A | Project-B |
Bill     | Project-D |           |           | Project-B | Project-C | Project-A |
Susan    | Project-C | Project-A |           |           | Project-B | Project-D |
Cathy    | Project-C | Project-A | Project-C | Project-A |           |           |
Jack     | Project-B | Project-C | Project-B | Project-B |           | Project-D |
Kate     |           | Project-B | Project-A | Project-D | Project-A | Project-C |
Anne     | Project-D |           |           | Project-C | Project-B | Project-A |
George   | Project-A | Project-D |           |           | Project-C | Project-B |
```

Now i don't know if some people are working more often together or in the worst case never.
**The goal is to balance the people working together on each project equally by moving the different projects.**
E.g. Bob & Jennifer shall not work together every time (worst case planning).

**Output:**

```
Counts working together:
         | Bob      | Jennifer | Tom      | Bill    | Susan    | Cathy
Bob      |-         | 0        | 0        | 0       | 0        | 0        
Jennifer | 0        |-         | 0        | 0       | 0        | 0 
Tom      | 0        | 0        | -        | 0       | 0        | 2
Bill     | 0        | 0        | 0        | -       | 0        | 0
Susan    | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0       | -        | 2
Cathy    | 0        | 0        | 2        | 0       | 2        | -
```

Tried with *vlookup* or *countifs*, but it's a huge, huge formula. 
Is there a simple solution in excel to count two same expressions(e.g. Project-A) and then count +1 if e.g. Bob and Tom work on the same project?

thank you,

br

Comment: Do you want to count how many times they work together on a given date or just if they have worker on the same project during a week?

Comment: Further, your output doesnt make sense to me. Bob and Jennifer doesn't work together 5 times in your example.

Comment: i want to count how many times they work together during a week

Comment: @MrML sorry for the bad example, i just wanted to give an example of how i imagined the output to be visualized. edited the table to mach with the given Data

Answer (score 2):

This is just going across the rows for each pair of employees and seeing how many times the project names match in the same day:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX($B$2:$G$11,MATCH($I2,$I$2:$I$11,0),0)=INDEX($B$2:$G$11,MATCH(J$1,$J$1:$S$1,0),0))
*(INDEX($B$2:$G$11,MATCH($I2,$I$2:$I$11,0),0)<>""))
```

**Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Note

The row lookup isn't really needed  because the list of names in A2:A11 is in the same order as the list of names in I2:I11, but I am assuming this might not always be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure this out through a normal formula ! So here's my attempt with VBA which requires bit of setup.

You will have to create a master sheet which will keep track of the allocation by projects.

[image]

Now given that your weekly sheet is in this layout

[image]

You can run this code **eui**

```
Sub eqi()
Dim temp As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

With Sheets("weekly")

For k = 1 To 4 Step 1
    For i = 2 To 8 Step 1
        For j = 2 To 11 Step 1
        If .Cells(j, i).Value = Sheets("master").Cells(1, 3 + k).Value Then
        temp = temp + .Cells(j, 1).Value
        End If
        Next j
            If Not temp = "" Then
                Call Findcombination(temp, k)
            End If
        temp = ""
    Next i
Next k

End With
End Sub

Sub Findcombination(temp As String, k As Integer)
Dim rFound As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    With Sheets("master")
        Set rFound = .Columns(1).Find(What:=temp, After:=.Cells(2, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        rFound.Offset(, k + 2).Value = rFound.Offset(, k + 2).Value + 1
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then Application.Goto rFound, True
    End With
End Sub
```

Once you run the code it will fill the allocated combination by projects by 1 ideally you should have 1 everywhere.
If you run the code and get value 2 then it means the two have already worked together on the same project before.

If you don't want it by project then simply do a summation in column H of the master sheet if it's more than 1 then they have already worked together in the week.

[image]